# How to rescue oracle instance having oradata and admin?

Tags: oracle, restore

I have copy of oracle folder, installed on windows. There are have oradata and admin folders.
It is Oracle 9.2.0.8.0.

I had working WibXP operation system, and installed oracle there. Now WinXP, doesn't starts. And I want to setup exists instance of other cpmputer. Thats my sistuation

Comment: sounds desperate .. desperate enough to give us more info - what happened, what should be there, what needs to happen - so we can try to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly: you have a copy of an oracle folder containing the admin and oradata directories from another computer that is no longer operational?

If that is so, here's generically what I would try. Your directory structure where your database files reside must be identical to the original system, else you'll have additional work to do.

1. Install Oracle 9.2.0.8 on your new system (do not create a starter database)
2. Create a new Oracle instance with the oradim utility:

   oradim -new -sid oldSID -syspwd password
3. From a windows command prompt:

   set oracle_sid="yourSID"
   sqlplus /nolog
   conn / as sysdba
   startup pfile="path to admin\pfile\init.ora"

Hopefully, this will bring the instance up.